# How to execute Visual Studio with cmd after installing it in Windows?

Tags: visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuBD2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yevus.png)
I am going to install Visual Studio in Windows.

Could you tell me what I am supposed to do with this situation?

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people to help more people

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know the installation path of your Visual Studio. You can right-click Visual Studio on your desktop and click Properties to find its path. For example, mine is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE \devenv.exe

[image]

Then open cmd and enter

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE
```

Then enter

```
devenv.exe
```

[image]

**Second update:**

This is because you have not turned on "File name extensions", so your file does not display the suffix name. You only need to check "File name extensions".

[image]

According to your description, the devenv you are talking about should be devenv.exe

This is my devenv.exe:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have followed your suggestion and tried to figure out where the "devenv.exe" is, but I failed to find it. The only one which relates to "devenv" is a file named "devenv", without the ".exe", and this file is just a image of visual studio. (I embed a image for my question)
What a strange problem, could you please help me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @raingood devenv is a picture? Can Visual Studio open when you double click on it

Comment: Yeah, that is really strange, it just shows a picture of Visual Studio when I double click on it. Actually, I turned on "File name extensions", but there is no devenv.exe file.
Maybe there are some errors during the process of installation, how about deleting and reinstalling it?

Comment: This is really strange, it would be a good idea to reinstall Visual Studio at this time